# Can there be a better method than condition checking ? would switch be more efficient?

Tags: ruby, if-statement, conditional-operator

if i have to produce a result like this:

```
0001
0002
.
.
.
0099
0100
.
.
0184

for i in 1..184
    a = i.to_s
    if a.length == 1
        puts "000"+ a
    elsif a.length == 2
        puts "00"+ a
    else
        puts "0"+ a
    end
end
```

can there be a better and more efficient method than this instead of so much condition checking ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want to zero-pad an integer?

```
184.times{ |n| puts "%04d" % (n + 1) }
```

Comment: Just to add to this answer, you could also use a range and each like:
(1..184).each{|n| puts "%04d" % n}

Comment: Awesome i had no clue you call zero padding.

Comment: One last thing lol following your logic you could have done: 
`for i in 1..184  
 a = i.to_s  
 puts "0"*(4-a.size) + a  
end`